# Convert an if & vlookup combination formula to arrayformula - Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have this formula working in Google Sheets:

```
=if(B3="",0,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(E3,E4:E,1,FALSE)),1,0))
```

The logic is pretty straight forward:
if B3 is NOT NULL and there is no duplicate of E3 in range E4:E, write 1 else write 0

I tried to convert it to ARRAYFORMULA, coz it should be applied to all columns in E as and when the number of rows increase (via form submission), by doing this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B3="",0,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(E3:E,E4:E,1,FALSE)),1,0)))
```

But, it wrote 0 to all columns of E.

The reason here is that, the VLOOKUP should look in the E column range excluding the current row. I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Here is the [Google Spreadsheet (please refer to Sheet2)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11PNXgVT2-tsQ46Pvj9pki1jG4Of_WZCQjPJhG56lFOg/edit?usp=sharing)

Can someone please correct my ARRAYFORMULA? Thank you.

Comment: You can offset inside arrayformula now: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74260545/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't offset range used in `ArrayFormula`, so your original formula cannot be converted into `ArrayFormula` and remain result. But you may use this workaround:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(--(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(E3,,,COUNTA(A3:A)),QUERY({ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A3:A))), OFFSET(E3,,,COUNTA(A3:A))},"select Col2, max(Col1) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2 label Col2 '', max(Col1) ''"),2,0)=ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A3:A)))),0))`

I used `row` function in this formula to compare it with maximum row when certain value appears.

[Your sample file](http://I%20used%20%60row%60%20function%20is%20this%20formula%20to%20compare%20it%20with%20maximum%20row%20when%20certain%20value%20appears.)

Comment: Wow! That worked as expected. However, I did not understand the logic used.. Thanks a lot Max, you made my day :D