# How to use arrayformula with formulas that do not seem to support arrayformulas?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

If an array is provided as an input to a normally scalar argument of some functions like:

- `INDEX`
- `GCD`
- `GOOGLETRANSLATE`
- `OFFSET`
- `QUERY`
- `IMPORTRANGE`
- `AND`

It doesn't return an array (even if wrapped by ARRAYFORMULA); it only gets the value for the first item in the array. Take this example,

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |
| 7 | G |

I want to get row 1 and row 5's `Value`. I tried

```
=INDEX(A2:B16,{1;5},2)
```

Syntax for `INDEX` is `INDEX(array, row,column)`. When a array is provided as a row argument, It only returns the value for first item, `1`  instead of returning the value for `{1;5}`.

| Actual output | Expected output |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
|  | E |

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the result you're looking for, you can use `BYROW` to  supply the argument once per array:

```
=BYROW({1;5},LAMBDA(row,INDEX(A2:B16,row,2)))
```

`BYROW`  sends the array argument provided once per row to the function inside `LAMBDA`. As a general formula,

```
=BYROW(range, LAMBDA(row, your_formula(row)))
```

If you want to send two arguments, use `MAP` instead.

```
=MAP({1;5},{1;2},LAMBDA(arr_1,arr_2,INDEX(A2:B16,arr_1,arr_2)))
```

This will get row 1, column 1 and row 5, column 2 respectively.

| Actual output |
| --- |
| 1 |
| E |

`MAP` supports unlimited number of arguments and therefore can be used with complex formulas.

Caveat: *Only one value per function can be returned. If you want to return more values, use `SPLIT/TRANSPOSE/SPLIT` technique mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74078247)*